# how to expose prometheus metrics from spring boot apps registered with spring cloud eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-micrometer

I am trying to implement prometheus monitoring for spring boot apps but my spring boot apps are registered with spring cloud eureka server so I don't have an option to configure static ports for the apps in prometheus config, I can only configure **scraping** for eureka server like below but not for the apps registered with eureka. Can anyone please suggest?

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ["http://mycompany.eurekaserver.net:8761"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here to add new answer that, Eureka SD is supported now in Prometheus from 2.21 version onwards.
Documentation available at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#eureka_sd_config

Sample configuration is available at [Sample Eureka SD config](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.24/documentation/examples/prometheus-eureka.yml)

Answer (score 0):

Currently eureka server has no direct integration with prometheus, so we have to use SD adapter, I would recommend below, which is working as expected without much effort.

https://github.com/twinformatics/eureka-consul-adapter